# How much UV light do we have on the ground?

Tags: optics, geophysics

We cannot see it. But suppose each UV photon is replaced by a red light photon, does it make the world look as bright as it is just before the sunrise?

Comment: The answer to this will depend on the time of day, and whether there is cloud cover... UV as fraction of daylight changes. Not sure what "as bright as just before the sunrise" means either. 30 minutes before sunrise in Helsinki in summer the sky is bright; in Jakarta it would still be solid night...

Comment: Pick a day and time and latitude, and there are plenty of websites that'll give you the spectral power density at the ground.  Convert power to photons/second,  then convert that many red photons to equivalent photopic levels.  Not trivial but a good exercise if you want to learn about black-body curves and such.